# What's the term for people who think they suffering from imposter syndrome when in reality they *are* imposters?

Tags: emotional-responses

Many academics and students claim to be suffering from imposter syndrome. Many of these will be strong contributors regardless and I hope they find a way to cope with their self-esteem issues.

However, some of these actually *will be* imposters, and their feelings are appropiate and accurate indicators of their actual level of intellect and knowledge. Some of these people even claim to be suffering from imposter syndrome, when in fact their concerns are well justified.

What's a name for such people?

For example, there's a guy I know who often talks about how he has imposter syndrome because he often feels inadequate and outperformed in comparison to other students in our class. I don't know how to tell him that our class (in my experience) is wholly average and anybody who can't keep up with the level simply doesn't have the intellect/knowledge/effort required.

Comment: I guess the term would be imposters. But if you don't think your classmate is up to snuff, you should probably keep that to yourself unless he comes to you asking for brutally honest feedback. (Even then, you should probably point him to someone whose place it is to give such feedback, e.g. one of his professors.)

Comment: In general it is a mistake to characterize other individuals. Some people just struggle and don't know why. Some people need more self confidence, while others need more study. Overconfidence in your abilities can also be a problem. People are just _messy_ in general. We have a couple hundred thousand years of muddling through.

Comment: And what does this have to do with academia?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi - at least in the US, imposter syndrome has received a lot of attention lately in academia, grad school specifically (though I'm sure you're right and other, non-academic professionals also experience it)

Comment: @cag51 So? It's a question about the English language.

Comment: Echoing @NajibIdrissi: either this is a question about the English language; or it is a question whose main point seems to be to make a complaint. While I sympathise with frustration that may occur when encountering this situation, I suggest you try to formulate an explicit question about practice or norms

Comment: How about "clueless"?

Answer (score 7):

**I don't think there is any specific word**. The people you describe are just **below average** or (relatively) **low-achieving**. I guess they could be labeled **imposters**, but I've never heard this used. That they claim imposter syndrome may make them **delusional**, but they could also just be mistaken -- it's notoriously difficult to accurately judge one's own abilities.

**But, below-average students aren't necessarily imposters.** Most classes have bell curves, and people on the lower half of the bell curve can still do fine work and earn their degree (and may well suffer from "imposter syndrome" if they assess their abilities far below their actual level). "True imposters" would be outliers so far below average that they should not have been admitted and are unlikely to be able to honestly earn the degree.